# Create a Fat jar to package multiple jars

Tags: scala, sbt, azure-databricks, uberjar, fatjar

I am using Databricks cluster to execute spark application..
My application having some dependency on few libraries but now these libraries are not available via the Databricks install new library option.
I came to know the through the Fat jar or Uber jar I can add multiple libraries and pass this to the cluster.
I also came to know that to create a fat jar you have to provide a main class so I have written a simple program in my local system and added the dependencies to the build.sbt file.
I am using the 'sbt assembly' command to create fat jar.
Please note that I am not using the library in my sample program.

My aim is to create a fat jar that inherits all the required jar in it so that my other Spark based application can access the libraries via this fat jar..

I did the following steps.

### 'Sample Program'

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    print("Hello World")
  }

}
```

### 'Build.sbt'

```
name := "CrealyticsFatJar"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.crealytics/spark-excel
libraryDependencies += "com.crealytics" %% "spark-excel" % "0.12.0"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

### 'assembly.sbt'

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")
```

But I am not sure whatever I am doing is correct and will help to execute my spark programs in Databricks cluster.

**Q1)** There might be some possibility that one library having dependency on the other library so If I have mention the library name in SBT then would it load other dependent libraries?
**Q2)** If I am not using the libraries to the existing program would it be available to the other program of the cluster.
**Q3)** After the installation of Fat jar in cluster- how do I access the libraries.. I mean by which name I would access the libraries..the import command...

Apologies if my questions are so silly.
Thanks

Comment: _"BT then would it load other dependent libraries"_ yes, no worry about that. _"would it be available to the other program of the cluster."_ No, each program has its own classpath, that is the key word to learn more about that. - "would it be available to the other program of the cluster"_ you are not installing it, you just run it. If you want  to install many libraries on your cluster that is a different story, you would need to upload ll the jars to a common location, again learn more about classpath to understand how this works.

Comment: Finally, that is not the correct way. You need to mark the **spark** dependencies as `provided` and exclude the scala standard library from the fat jar: `assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)`

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez can you please help me out of the issue.. still I am not sure How to deal with such kind of problem..

Comment: Sorry I do not understand, what problem? what you are doing is correct you create an **SBT** project with your application code and your dependencies, create the fat jar and deploy it into your cluster. I just warned you that you need to mark the spark base dependencies as `Provided` and the scala std library has to be excluded of that jar.

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez  can I create a fat jar without writing any sample program??

Comment: and how Would I let my spark application know where actually the library exist..the import statement...

Comment: I mean the idea is that you create a **Jar** with all the dependencies for each of your programs. If what you want to do is to install some dependencies on a cluster so they are available for jupyter notebooks or other applications then it would be better to rewrite the question to be more clear.

Comment: @ Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez - So basically nothing is wrong.. I had few doubts but most of the things are clear to me..